# Lemma 1.3.11. (Kashiwara & Schapira), Zorn's Lemma?

Tags: category-theory

> **Lemma 1.3.11.** Consider a functor $F: C \to C'$ and a full subcategory $C_0'$ of $C'$ such that for each $X \in C$, there exist $Y \in C_0'$ and an isomorphism $F(X) \simeq Y$. Denote by $\iota$ the embedding $C_0' \to C'$.  Then there exists a functor $F_0 : C \to C_0'$ and an isomorphism of functors $\theta_0:F \xrightarrow{\sim} \iota'\circ F_0$.  Moreover, $F_0$ is unique up to unique isomorphism.  More precisely, given another isomorphism $\theta_1 : F \xrightarrow{\sim} \iota'\circ F_1$, there exists a unique isomorphism of functors $\theta: F_1 \xrightarrow{\sim} F_0$ such that $\theta_0 = (\iota'\circ \theta)\circ \theta_1$.
>
> *Proof*.  Using Zorn's Lemma, for each $X \in C$, choose $Y \in C_0'$ and an isomorphism $\varphi_X : Y \xrightarrow{\sim} F(X)$, and set $F_0(X) = Y$. [...]

How are they using Zorn's Lemma here?   Zorn's Lemma is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice, so that might explain the word "choose."

Comment: Probably by proving the axiom of choice, and then choosing using that.

Comment: But, wow, we make a choice for each member of a *class*. Isn't that a tough job even for the axiom of choice?

Comment: @Hagen: That is also true. But maybe Zorn's lemma is given for classes, in which case it's not that of a heavy lifting! Or, you know, universes.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Kashiwara/Shapira only work inside a fixed Universe all over their book.

Comment: @Jakob: In that case they don't need class version of choice anyway, since the axiom of choice is enough to provide "global choice for the universe". Or do you mean, by that, that they work internally to a universe of $\sf ZFC$? (rather than inside a universe which is a set inside a larger universe of $\sf ZFC$)

Comment: @Asaf Yes, I wanted to say that they only use standard AC for sets. Of course this does not explain, why they call it Zorn's Lemma, but well, weird terminology and notation seems to be a speciality of this book.